# guardar arreglos en mysql con reactjs y php

Tags: php, reactjs, react-hooks

tengo un formulario en reactjs el cual tiene una variable normal que se llama "nombre" y dos arreglos uno se llama "dato1" y el otro "dato2", pero al darle guardar desde reactjs solo me esta guardando la variable "nombre" en base de datos.

**Necesito que tambien me guarden los arreglos en base de datos pero no lo he logrado.**

la base de datos en mysql solo tiene una tabla que se llama ingresos2 y 4 campos: id_ingreso,nombre,dato1,dato2

https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-browser-nvcee?file=/src/App.js

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import {
  Grid,
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableContainer,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
  Paper
} from "@material-ui/core";
import AddCircleOutlineIcon from "@material-ui/icons/AddCircleOutline";
import { withStyles, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";

const StyledTableRow = withStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    "&:nth-of-type(odd)": {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.hover
    }
  }
}))(TableRow);

const options = [
  { value: 1, label: 1 },
  { value: 2, label: 2 },
  { value: 3, label: 3 }
];

function Pruebas() {
    const baseUrlAd = 'https://www.inventarios.gemcont.com/apiGemcont/compras/ingresos/'; 
    const [data, setData]=useState([]);
    const [frameworkSeleccionado, setFrameworkSeleccionado]=useState({
        id_ingreso:'',
        nombre:'',
        dato1:'',
        dato2:''
      });

    const handleChange=e=>{
        const {name, value}=e.target;
        setFrameworkSeleccionado((prevState)=>({
          ...prevState,
          [name]: value
        }))
       console.log(frameworkSeleccionado);
      }

      const peticionPost = async() =>{
        var f = new FormData();
        f.append("nombre", frameworkSeleccionado.nombre);

        f.append("dato1", frameworkSeleccionado.dato1);
        f.append("dato2", frameworkSeleccionado.dato2);
        f.append("METHOD", "POST_prueba");
        await axios.post(baseUrlAd,f)
        .then(response=>{
         setData(data.concat(response.data));
        }).catch(error=>{
          console.log(error);
        })
    
      }


  const [roomInputs, setRoomInputs] = useState([
    { dato1: "", dato2: "" }
  ]);

  
  const handleRoomChange = (value, index, name) => {
    const list = [...roomInputs ];
    list[index][name] = value;
    setRoomInputs(list);
  };

  const handleRemoveClickRoom = (index) => {
    const list = [...roomInputs];
    list.splice(index, 1);
    setRoomInputs(list);
  };

  const handleAddClickRoom = () => {
    setRoomInputs([...roomInputs, { dato1: "", dato2: "" }]);
  };

  
 
    return (
<div className="content-wrapper">
    
    <div className="content-header">
      <div className="container-fluid">
        
          <div className="col-sm-12">

          <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
              <h3 class="card-title">Datos</h3>
              </div>
            
              <div class="card-body">
                
                  <div class="row">  

                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" name="nombre"
                  placeholder='nombre' className="form-control" onChange={handleChange}/>
                  </div>
                  </div>


                  </div>

                  <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                  
                  
        <br />
          <Grid item sm={12}>
            <TableContainer component={Paper} variant="outlined">
              <Table  aria-label="customized table">
                <TableHead>
                  <TableRow>
                    <TableCell>#</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="left">dato1</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="left">dato2</TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                  
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                  {roomInputs.map((x, i) => (
                    <StyledTableRow key={i}>
                      <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                        {i + 1}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="left">
                        <input 
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        name="dato1"
                        value={options.value}
                        //onChange={option => handleRoomChange(option, i, "dato1")}
                        onChange={event => handleRoomChange(event.target.value, i, "dato1")}
                        />
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="left">
                      <input 
                        type="number"
                        name="dato2"
                        className="form-control"
                        value={options.value}
                        //onChange={option => handleRoomChange(option, i, "dato2")}
                        onChange={event => handleRoomChange(event.target.value, i, "dato2")}
                        />
                      </TableCell>

            

                      <TableCell align="left">
                        {roomInputs.length !== 1 && (
                          <DeleteIcon
                            onClick={() => handleRemoveClickRoom(i)}
                            style={{
                              marginRight: "10px",
                              marginTop: "4px",
                              cursor: "pointer"
                            }}
                          />
                        )}
                        {roomInputs.length - 1 === i && (
                          <AddCircleOutlineIcon
                            onClick={handleAddClickRoom}
                            style={{ marginTop: "4px", cursor: "pointer" }}
                          />
                        )}
                      </TableCell>
                    </StyledTableRow>
                  ))}
                </TableBody>
               
                  
              </Table>
            </TableContainer>
          </Grid>
         
      
     
             </div>
                  </div>
                  <br />
                  <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={()=>peticionPost()}> Registrar</button>
               
              </div>
             
            </div>     

      </div>

      </div>
      </div>
    
  </div>
    )
}


export default Pruebas
```

php

```js
<?php

include '../../bd/global.php';

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');


if($_POST['METHOD']=='POST_prueba'){
    unset($_POST['METHOD']);
    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
    $dato1=$_POST['dato1'];
    $dato2=$_POST['dato2'];
    $query="insert into ingresos2(nombre,dato1,dato2) values ('$nombre','$dato1','$dato2')";
    $queryAutoIncrement="select MAX(id_ingreso) as id_ingreso from ingresos2";
    $resultado=metodoPost($query, $queryAutoIncrement);
    echo json_encode($resultado);
    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    exit();
}


header("HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request");


?>
```

Comment: Tu código puede sufrir los [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) asociados a la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyección_SQL). Por otro lado, ¿podrías mirar el inspector de red del navegador para decirnos qué está enviando la petición XHR?

Comment: si, tengo muy presente eso pero lo que necesito es poder guardar los arreglos que comente , ya despues mejoro la consulta.

Comment: Disculpa, estaba cenando. He encontrado tu problema, redacto respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código que has creado para enviar los datos al PHP no obtiene los datos de donde los estás almacenando.

Recuerda que estás almacenando los valores `dato1` y `dato2` en un elemento por cada fila de la tabla, por lo que deberás acceder al primer elemento de la matriz bidimensional `roomInputs` para acceder a las propiedades `dato1` y `dato2`.

Ya que quieres enviar múltiples valores a PHP existen diferentes maneras de hacerlo:

- Insertando en el formulario (`FormData f`) todos los valores mediante matrices incrementales (por ejemplo, `f.append("dato1[]", ...)`) y que PHP itere por cada uno de ellos.
- Enviar la información original en JSON y que PHP lo interprete e itere su contenido.

Nos vamos a centrar en este último método ya que, en mi opinión, es la mejor forma de hacerlo.

---

Enviando los datos desde Javascript a PHP:

```
  const peticionPost = async () => {
    await axios
      .post(baseUrlAd, {
        frameworkSeleccionado,
        roomInputs,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        setData(data.concat(response.data));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

Como puedes ver el código se ha simplificado enormemente. Se van a enviar dos propiedades, con nombres `frameworkSeleccionado` y `roomInputs` que contendrán el contenido de los objetos nombrados.

Ahora vayamos al lado del servidor, donde se reciben los datos. Allí lo más importante es la manera en la que PHP recibe los datos de Javascript:

```
$datos = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

Cuando se envían datos en el cuerpo de POST que no están codificados como datos de formulario (`multipart/form-data`) hay que recibir los datos a través de la entrada estándar (`php://input`) y, posteriormente, convertirlos en datos nativos de PHP mediante `json_decode()`.

Una vez obtenidos los datos podremos trabajar con ellos de la manera habitual.

Tu código podría quedar así (de manera esquemática, no conozco los detalles de tu implementación):

```
<?php
require_once "../../bd/global.php";

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
/* Si es una prueba prevuelo no debemos ejecutar el script */
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "OPTIONS") {
    die();
}

/* Si no nos han enviado el formulario */
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== "POST") {
    header("HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request");
    exit(1);
}

$datos = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
/* Si no son datos JSON devolvemos un error */
if ($datos === null) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request");
    exit(1);
}

/* NOTA: Habría que comprobar la validez de los datos antes de procesarlos */
$nombre = $datos->frameworkSeleccionado->nombre;
foreach ($datos->roomInputs as $habitacion) {
    /* Por cada habitación tienes los datos en:
        - $habitacion->dato1
        - $habitacion->dato2
    */
}
```

En el bucle `foreach` tienes posibilidad de agregar un elemento a la tabla por cada fila de la tabla.

La primera edición puede consultarse [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/517461/1).

Comment: ya probe pero tiene un inconveniente la solución que me envio, si coloco solo dos datos en el array dato1 y dato2 funciona pero aparte de colocar los datos en dato1 y dato2 le doy donde esta el + me da la opcion de colocar mas datos de dato1 y dato2 pero esos datos no me los guarda

Comment: subi al el codigo que me enviaste . " Si estás interesado en saber cómo enviarlos todos déjame un comentario y modifica el código para poder agregar más registros." quedo pendiente...

Comment: en la parte de php veo que falta la consulta para guardar los datos...

Comment: No conozco el funcionamiento de tu función `metodoPost()`, por lo que no puedo sugerirte mejoras en ese apartado. Cuando quieras puedes compartir en una nueva pregunta el código para indicarte cómo arreglar el problema de inyección SQL y hacer múltiples inserciones con una única consulta preparada.

Comment: en la pregunta que hice, ahi esta el codigo php de la funcion post donde inserta los datos a la base de datos mysql

Comment: Si no lo arreglas y preparas tu código para insertar varios registros no podré mostrarte el código en mi respuesta. Por ejemplo, tu función `metodoPost()` devuelve el resultado que debe devolverse a Javascript, pero como hay que hacer varias llamadas de inserciones no sé qué debería devolver tu PHP. Además, estaríamos cambiando el tema de esta pregunta. En esta pregunta te he respondido a la duda de cómo enviar datos desde React.js a PHP, así que para arreglar la parte de PHP deberías crear una nueva pregunta compartiendo en ella el código de dicha función.

Comment: listo, voy a crear otra pregunta.